# Line breaks handled inconsistently by SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

Probably more of a SQL Management Studio question than SQL, per se, but when I run the following simple query:

```
SELECT results = 'Foo' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Bar'
```

I appear to get different results depending on whether I choose "Results to Grid" or "Results to Text".

With SSMS set to "Results to Text", I get (as expected):

```
results
--------
Foo
Bar

(1 row affected)
```

But with SSMS set to "Results to Grid", then copy and paste the results, I get

```
Foo  Bar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option to change this behavior, go to `Tools > Options > Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Grid`, and check the box for "Retain CR/LF on copy or save":

[image]

You may have to exit and re-load SSMS for this change to take effect.